# The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context MySolution.DNX 4.5.1 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and have the below code in my MVC project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Web;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace Site.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error stating:

> The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context  MySolution.DNX 4.5.1

I've added the following Nuget packages:

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
Microsoft.Owin.Security

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Are you using AspNet 6 (vNext)?

Comment: @Robert how do I tell if it's 6?  I'm using Visual Studio 2015, my project.json has under "frameworks" dnx451, i removed dnxcore50.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Asp.Net 6 (vNext):

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

public MyComponent(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
    this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
}

public string GetDataFromSession() {
    return contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(*KEY*);
}
```

You now access the HttpContext in this manner. I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this and now i'm getting an error that GetOwinContext() does not exist in HttpContext, with this line contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication

Comment: I changed it to System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication; and am not getting an error anymore